# Order of import statements in java

Tags: java, import

Just to know. Which is the proper way of ordering import statements? Also which has more readability?

like,

- External classes (like `java.util.List`) and then internal package
  classes.
- Just in alphabetical order

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Freaking compiler would not recognize classes from `javax.xml.bind.annotation` on nested classes after IDEA reorganized the imports for me. The solution? I configured IDEA to add the imports in this sequence: `java.*`, `javax.*`, `org.*`, `com.*`, `net.*`, `io.*` and the rest at the end. Looks like `java.*` imports must go before `javax.*` ones. This ordering kinda matters, wow. Have that in mind.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [Java Programming Style Guidelines](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#Package%20and%20Import%20Statements)

> The import statements must follow the package statement. import
>   statements should be sorted with the most fundamental packages first,
>   and grouped with associated packages together and one blank line
>   between groups.
>
> ..... .....
>
> The import statement location is enforced by the Java
>   language. The sorting makes it simple to browse the list when there
>   are many imports, and it makes it easy to determine the dependiencies
>   of the present package The grouping reduce complexity by collapsing
>   related information into a common unit.

Refere the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) link for more info.

Comment: I agree with the quote but IMHO it's worth mentioning that the quoted document "Java Programming Style Guidelines" is not written by Sun/Oracle. As I understand it, it's only based on the [original guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) but is otherwise written by [GeoSoft - Geotechnical Software Services](http://geosoft.no/) and I'm not sure about their authority in these matters. Unfortunately the original Sun/Oracle documentation does not provide guidelines for the order of imports. I think this is up to the individual project/organisation to define.

Comment: Adding to @void256's comment, Google's [Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.3.3-import-ordering-and-spacing) recommends only a single blank line between static and non-static imports. So it is really up to the project to define the guidelines.

Answer (score 18):

Most preferred, and used in most IDE, is alphabetical ordering, starting from domain level and a fully qualified class name.

`java.*` and `javax.*` takes precedence, and the rest are ordered.

Example:

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.neurologic.http.HttpClient;
import com.neurologic.http.impl.ApacheHttpClient;
```

Comment: "rest are ordered", but how it comes that `org` precedes `com`? I've just found such a setting in my Eclipse and wonder where it comes from.

Comment: @maaartinus Good question. I have no idea. Perhaps because `org` is a shortened organizational, so it deems it a priority? ;)

Comment: org is short for organization, just as com is short for commercial. as in amazon.com and iso.org

Comment: Often, the "own" packages come below imported libraries. This is also in line with the idea of ordering it from most general to specific. Most general is the java library, then some other libs such as apache, and finally the actual project.

Answer (score 6):

Im not sure if there is a standard. But some projects such like android use the following rule.

1. First import project specific files (android)
2. Second comes the third party files and library.
3. The java standard api files.

Each group is seperated by an extra line. And each group has their imports in alphabetical order.

AFAIK these are based on our preference.

Answer (score 4):

I just use the default order that my IDE (Eclipse) implements ... and regularly run the "Tidy Imports" thingy to keep the house in order.

Readability is not a significant concern if you automate this.  You will quickly get used to any automated ordering, no matter what it is.  Besides, people tend not to *read* imports anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer alphabetical order - this is the most readable, isn't it...

Comment: the problem is that is not the default settings of any of the most popular IDEs...

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, if you're using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, readability isn't too much of a concern because you start to trust that the organization is automated and perfect.

The one area, then, where order does matter, is defining the precedence if you have multiple classes with the same name potentially imported via a `.*` notation.

For example, say you have `java.util.List` and `org.northpole.christmas.List` available and you specify imports `java.util.*` and `org.northpole.christmas.*`  Then in this case it makes sense to have `java.util.*` higher than `org.northpole.christmas.*` because if I wasn't really paying that much attention and I was reading the code later, I would assume that `List` is `java.util.List` and not something else. This is why, I believe, Eclipse has `java` and `javax` first, then `org.apache`, then others.  These days I also slip `com.google` in above or below `org.apache`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer  this :

1) First group imports based on external and internal APIs
2)Alphabetically within each group

Answer (score 0):

Most of the IDEs does this Job nicely. Just right click and say "Organize Imports".